# Copy specific files to specific directory with loop in bash

Tags: shell-script

What I'm trying to do is:

```
src1=/path/to/source1
src2=/path/to/source2

dest1=/path/to/dest1
dest2=/path/to/dest2

loop

    copy src(x) to dest(x)   #here x=1,2,3..

break_loop
```

So how can I achieve this in bash script?

Answer (score 1):

As a variant, assuming you have bash for shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A dirs
dirs[/path/to/source1]=/path/to/dest1
dirs[/path/to/source2]=/path/to/dest2
for src in "${!dirs[@]}"
do
   cp -- "$src"/* "${dirs[$src]}"/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

So i am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you are simply trying to copy src1 to dest1 and src2 to dest2 then you can do something like this:

```
src=(/path/to/source1 /path/to/source2)

dest=(/path/to/dest1 /path/to/dest2)

for i in "${!src[@]}"; do
    cp -- "${src[$i]}" "${dest[$i]}"
done
```

Hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: Actually, I was trying to make a script to periodically upload some directories from my local machine to a cloud storage. I'm using rclone (https://github.com/rclone/rclone) for this, which works just like cp. And thanks for your answer, I'll definitely try it out.